# What is faster Communicating, sending broadcast VS calling activity method directly in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-broadcast

In my app, I have to call an activity method from the fragment.

I know I can do this in two ways:

**1. Via sending a broadcast to activity:**

`Intent intent = new Intent("FILTER");
 intent.putExtra("EXTRA", 1);
 sendBroadcast(intent);`

**2. Or Calling the activity method directly:**

`((MyActivity) getActivity()).method();`

I would like to know which way is faster and safe to communicate. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use a listener (Interface) as well to communicate back to Activity. And I have never seen anyone using a BroadcastReceiver to bridge a Fragment and Activity Communication.

Comment: Use interface, it will be better, activity will implement the interface, and fragment will call the method using listener

Comment: why don't you log the time in logcat and see yourself which is faster?

Comment: I'm against the second method because it means the fragment can't live without the specific MyActivity class. It also assumes the activity it's attached to is always of type MyActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Loosely Coupled Fragment?

I am not sure about the speed. But on the design perspective You should use an interface to communicate with an Activity rather calling Activity method directly from your Fragment. ie   `((MyActivity) getActivity()).method();`

> Because using an interface makes your Fragment independent from your
>   Activity. Let's say in future you want to use your fragment in Some
>   other Activity then you will not have to change anything in your
>   Fragment.

**Interface**

```
public interface Somelistener {

     public void someMethod();

}
```

**Your Loosely coupled Fragment**

```
YourFragment extends Fragment {

   Somelistener listener;

    public void onActivityCreated(Context context){

      listener = (SomeLisner)context;

    }

    public void buttonClick()
    {
       listener.someMethod();
    }

}
```

So if you are using in your `MainActivity`. **No problem**

```
MainActivity implements SomeListener{

   @Override
   public void someMethod()
   {
      // Activity method
   }
}
```

In future you want to use Fragment in `SomeOtherActivity`. **No problem**

```
SomeOtherActivity implements SomeListener{

   @Override
   public void someMethod()
   {
      // somethother method
   }
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver Approach?**
TBH I have seen this approach for Service-Activity Communication. Not for Activity - Fragment communication.

Answer (score 1):

For communicating between Fragments and the Activity that contains it, there's actually a much better 3rd option.

The better option is to use an Interface as a callback method. This is described very well in this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Using an interface is much more preferred over your two methods because it's both safer and more efficient.

For your first method of using Broadcast Receivers, this is actually a very inefficient solution due to Broadcast Receivers not being meant for a task like what you're after.

Let me quote you something from the Android documentation:

> Warning: Limit how many broadcast receivers you set in your app. Having too many broadcast receivers can affect your app's performance and the battery life of users' devices. For more information about APIs you can use instead of the BroadcastReceiver class for scheduling background work, see Background Optimizations.
>   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element

So yes, Broadcast Receivers will have a bigger effect on your app's performance and the device's battery life over the other method you suggested and the method I suggested.

Additionally, don't forget that a Broadcast Receiver is meant to listen to broadcasts. The type of Broadcast Receiver you're using in your example is actually a Global Broadcast where you didn't explicitly limit it's "range", so any Broadcast Receiver could potentially "listen" in to your broadcast. In terms of security, using a Global Broadcast like this isn't safe either.

You also don't want other apps to potentially fire off a Broadcast that coincidentally coincides with your app's Broadcast Receiver, causing it to receive data not meant for it and crashing due to this accidental and coincidental naming.

Honestly, there's more potential issues of using a Broadcast Receiver in a way it's not meant for.

As for your second method of directly calling the Activity's method... this is actually very inefficient for managing code. You're basically tying the Fragment tightly together with that specific Activity.

However, Fragments, by design, makes it common to be swapped into other Activities or Fragments... you'll basically have to do multiple `if statements` and `casts` each time you want to run code from it's parent.

Also, keep in mind that if you later change code in MyActivity, it can cause problems for this fragment due to you forgetting how tightly bound it is to the Activity.

But if you use the more preferred Callback Interface approach, it's simply a middleman meant to deliver a "Hey, DO something for me" message. Quick and direct. It's also plays friendly with any Activity or Fragment you want to attach this Fragment to later since those Activities or Fragments simply have to implement the Interface and the callback bridge between both parent and child is formed.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use interface to communicate from fragment to activity rather than a Local broadcast.
Activity will implement the interface and fragment will call the methods.